# query to select a default value if a select comes empty

Tags: sql, ms-access

It is a simple question but I am having serious problems to make it work in Access.

I have a query to do:

```
Select * from Rates where client="Jhonsons"
```

But if it doesn't exist Jhonsons as client, it needs to select a general, running this query:

```
Select * from Rates where client="General"
```

That is it. It seems a simple task but is giving me really much challenging and I would appreciate some help on this.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: You can also use SQL CASE instead of top.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `top` and `order by`:

```
select top 1 r.*
from Rates as r
where client in ("Jhonsons", "General")
order by iif(client = "General", 2, 1)
```

There are other methods as well, such as:

```
select r.*
from Rates as r
where r.client = "Jhonsons" union all
select r.*
from Rates as r
where r.client = "General" and
      not exists (select 1 from Rates as r2 where r2.client = "Jhonsons") ;
```

Comment: @Parfait . . . I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional `iif` statement with the `exists` operator to test for the existence of the client record as part of the `where` clause, e.g.:

```sql
select r1.* from rates r1 
where r1.client = 
iif(exists (select 1 from rates r2 where r2.client = "Jhonsons"), "Jhonsons", "General")
```